# Assignment in Delete a node in Binary Search Tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Below is the code to delete a node in Binary Search Tree(BST)
https://leetcode.com/submissions/detail/730887683/

I have a doubt .Why are we doing below  i.e why are are assigning.

```
 root.left=deleteNode(root.left,key);
```

and why not

```
 deleteNode(root.left,key);
```

Similarly  for `root.right` .

Comment: What programming language is this?

Comment: @HezekiahBodine updated teh link which has complete code in java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine a BST with 3 nodes, with the `root` node as 5 and the `key` as 3.

```
   5
 /   \
3     6
```

When the key is deleted from the (root)node, the (root)node.left value should become null, if it's not null then the tree remains just as it was originally.

Hence, it's important to assign the deleted "null" value to the root.left.
`root.left=deleteNode(root.left,key);`